# Combining multiple geodatabases into one master geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.6

I currently have geodatabases for each project within a specified area. I would like to combine all of these geodatabases into one master geodatabase. Some of the geodatabases contain some of the same data and if combined into one master geodatabase there would be duplicates. Each database was made with the same template.

How could I go about combining these so the master geodatabase will reflect the updates made to each geodatabase I currently use?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. Unfortunately, this question is rather broad. Generally speaking, a single migration is not an issue, but attempting to maintain independent copies would require geodatabase replication and other advanced techniques.

Comment: Are these File, Personal, Enterprise or another type of Geodatabase?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before, and here is my answer. Hope it helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192317/finding-redundancy-between-two-layers/192321#192321

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into this [Merge Geodatabases](http://projects.sarasafavi.com/mergegeodatabases) tool which is an ArcGIS Script Tool.

> Note: this tool requires an active ArcGIS license.
>
> Merge one or more geodatabases with matching schemas into a single target geodatabase.
>
> Source and target geodatabases can be local (file) geodatabases or ArcSDE database connections. Any datasets or feature classes that do not match the target schema will be ignored. Duplicate data will be persisted if present (duplicate features will not be removed).

Answer (score 0):

Esri has a tool that can help you out with this situation. Apparently, you just mix it all up into 1 feature class (using Append tool), then use the Delete Identical tool on that master feature class to delete the duplicates: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm